# Error in set date oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My oracle have:

```
NLS_DATE_FORMAT     DD/MM/RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   SPANISH
```

and i execute

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';
alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN';

alter system set nls_date_format='DD-MON-RR'
```

And everything is correct, but when i reset sql developer change to

```
LS_DATE_FORMAT=DD/MM/RR other one
```

How can I change it forever?

Comment: I'm confused about your exact question. Title mentions an error but I'd say you aren't getting one. Session variables expire with session... as expected. System values are overridden by session values... of course. Is it just a question about how to display dates in SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0):

Your session settings might have been overwritten by SQL Developer when it relaunches.

To permanently fix it, Open `SQL Developer` and go to `Tools -> Preference -> Database -> NLS` and change `Date Format` to your required format there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use an after logon trigger. That way you can set your settings independent of the client (SQL Developer) used.